# I add a animation line under the title. but can't spread well

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I've googled the problem but couldn't find an solution for problem mentioned below

Here's my code:

```css
span.line-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
span.line {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #666;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
}
span .line-left {
  left: 0;
}
span .line-right {
  left: 50%;
}
span.line-wrap:hover span.line {
  width: 50%;
}
a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>
   <span class="line-wrap">
       <span class="line line-left"></span>
       <span class="line line-right"></span>
       <a href="xxx">Long long long title</a>
   </span>
</h2>
```

Currently it will animate in one direction like this:

```
Long long long long title.
----       -----
```

But I need it to animate like this.

```
Long long long long title.
       ----------
```

I know it dosen't works for now, but it might have a solution. But I have no idea. Please give me some suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Give more details... i don't think anyone understands what you want

Comment: Please make a working example. The code you have given doesn't do anything. Here, I have started it for you: https://jsfiddle.net/aa8tg2wc/

Comment: @AllTheTime, Thank you for your remind, next time i will show it in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a pseudo-element and a scale transform rather than actual unsemantic styling spans.

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color:rebeccapurple
}
a::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  background: currentColor;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform .35s ease;
}
a:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<h2>
       <a href="xxx">title</a>
</h2>
```